# Why is my perl hash not returning values?

Tags: perl, hash

I'm ingesting a CSV file:

```
"ID","LASTNAME","FIRSTNAME","PERM_ADDR1","PERM_ADDR2","PERM_CITY","PERM_ST","PERM_ZIP","DOB","LIB_TYPE","BARCODE","EMAIL","LOCAL_ADDR1","LOCAL_ADDR2","LOCAL_CITY","LOCAL_ST","LOCAL_ZIP","CAMPUS_ADDR1","CAMPUS_ADDR2","CAMPUS_CITY","CAMPUS_ST","CAMPUS_ZIP","DEPARTMENT","MAJOR"
"123","Lastname","Firstname","123 Home St","","Home City","HS","12345-6789","0101","S","1234567890","last.first@domain.local","123 Local St","","Local City","LS","98765-4321","123 Campus St","","Campus City","CS","54321-6789","IT",""
```

Using `Text::CSV`, I'm attempting to parse this into a hash:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

chomp(my $line = <READ>);
$csv->column_names(split(/,/, $line));

until (eof(READ)) {
    $line = $csv->getline_hr(*READ);
    my %linein = %$line;
    my %patron;

    $patron{'patronid'} = $linein{'ID'};
    $patron{'last'} = $linein{'LASTNAME'};
    $patron{'first'} = $linein{'FIRSTNAME'};

    print p(%linein)."\n";
    print p(%patron)."\n";
}
```

Using this code, the print statements at the end (using `Data::Printer`) return this:

```
{
    "BARCODE"        1234567890,
    "CAMPUS_ADDR1"   "123 Campus St",
    "CAMPUS_ADDR2"   "",
    "CAMPUS_CITY"    "Campus City",
    "CAMPUS_ST"      "CS",
    "CAMPUS_ZIP"     "54321-6789",
    "DEPARTMENT"     "IT",
    "DOB"            0101,
    "EMAIL"          "last.first@domain.local",
    "FIRSTNAME"      "Firstname",
    "ID"             123,
    "LASTNAME"       "Lastname",
    "LIB_TYPE"       "S",
    "LOCAL_ADDR1"    "123 Local St",
    "LOCAL_ADDR2"    "",
    "LOCAL_CITY"     "Local City",
    "LOCAL_ST"       "LS",
    "LOCAL_ZIP"      "98765-4321",
    "MAJOR"          "",
    "PERM_ADDR1"     "123 Home St",
    "PERM_ADDR2"     "",
    "PERM_CITY"      "Home City",
    "PERM_ST"        "HS",
    "PERM_ZIP"       "12345-6789"
}
{
    first      undef,
    last       undef,
    patronid   undef
}
```

What I don't understand is why `%patron` is not being populated with the values from `%linein`.  I'm wondering if this is somehow related to using `Text::CSV`, as I'm parsing other files elsewhere in the script and they work just fine.  Those files, however, are not CSV, but rather fixed-width, so I'm parsing them manually.

Comment: Try using `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(%patron);`.
If you can see the output as expected, then problem may be with `p()` subroutine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
 $csv->column_names(map {/"(.*)"/ and $1} split(/,/, $line))
```

Instead of

```
 $csv->column_names(split(/,/, $line));
```

Your CSV keys were being defined as the literal strings

```
 '"LASTNAME"' ,  '"FIRSTNAME"'
```

Instead of just

```
 'LASTNAME' ,  'FIRSTNAME'
```

`Data::Printer` wasn't doing too bad a job at showing you what was happening -
all the keys in `p(%linein)` are shown as containing double quotes as part of 
the string, as opposed to `p(%patron)`

Comment: After using your method (which worked), I realized that I hadn't completely understood the `Text::CSV->column_names()` method.  After re-reading the CPAN documentation, I tried `$csv->column_names($csv->getline(*READ));` which also worked, and has the advantage of being a little easier to read. Thanks!